# Como llamo el metodo requestCoffee al metodo on click

Tags: java, android

En el método `onClick` tengo que agregar el llamado al método `requestCoffe`
pero no se como realizarlo

```
private void requestCoffe(){
    RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            coffees=new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++){
                    Coffee coffee=new Coffee(response.getJSONObject(i));
                    coffees.add(coffee);
                }
                adapter=new CoffeeAdapter(coffees, MainActivity.this); //Modificar la creación del Adapter, agregando
                // la referencia a la clase como segundo argumento.
                recyclerCoffee.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No se puede conectar",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    queue.add(arrayRequest);
}

public void onClick(View view) {

}
```

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: coloca requestCoffe(); dentro del onClick (entre las llaves)

Answer (score -1):

Tu clase debe estar implementando `View.OnClickListener`

```
 implements View.OnClickListener {
```

se debe sobreescribir el método onClick():

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
```

y designar el listener a la vista que lo llamaría, por ejemplo:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Para realizar la petición Volley, agrega el llamado del método `requestCoffe()` dentro de `onClick()`:

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      requestCoffe();

    }
```

---

Aunque te recomiendo que la definición del `RequestQueue` puedas realizarla antes, por ejemplo dentro de `onCreate()` de tu `Activity`

```
   private RequestQueue queue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        ...
      }
```

ya que no necesitas definirlo cada vez que realizas la petición

```
private void requestCoffe(){
    //* RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            coffees=new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++){
                    Coffee coffee=new Coffee(response.getJSONObject(i));
                    coffees.add(coffee);
                }
                adapter=new CoffeeAdapter(coffees, MainActivity.this); //Modificar la creación del Adapter, agregando
                // la referencia a la clase como segundo argumento.
                recyclerCoffee.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No se puede conectar",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    queue.add(arrayRequest);
}
```

Comment: Observación: falta agregarle el listener a la vista asociada. En caso de que vaya a utilizar el click.

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.